# Placement of express static files

Tags: express, passport.js

I was building authentication for my webapp when I ran into an error. It happened to do with the express static files . Does it matter where this line,

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/dist')));
```

is placed in my server.js because if I place the above line above my `app.get('/)`
request , my authentication does not work.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you answered your own question.

Comment: I didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it matter where this line is placed.

Yes, it does.  Router handlers are processed in the order they are defined and the first one that matches, gets the first crack at the incoming request.

If you have a route that would match something in your `express.static()` line of code, but you want that to be matched by your `app.get(...)`, then you have to either put the `app.get(...)` route definition before the `express.static()` or change things (url paths or available files in the static directory) so the `app.get(...)` route can never be matched by your `express.static()` middleware.

We could help explain in more detail if you showed the actual URL you are using and then we can discuss what exactly that URL might be matching via the `express.static()` line in your `client/dist` directory.